# Why is my XmlWriter holding onto its file stream?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlwriter

I wrote an application that at one point writes an XML document. Later, a new object is created and at the same section in code, the `XmlWriter` cannot be opened because the file is still 'in use' by my program. In looking for an answer, I saw a lot of threads where the answer was to set `CloseOutput` to true before creating the `XmlWriter`, and to create it within a using block. I have done both of these and still have this problem.

```
XmlWriterSettings xSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xSettings.Indent = true;
xSettings.IndentChars = "\t";
xSettings.CloseOutput = true;

using (XmlWriter xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sOutputFileName, xSettings))
{
    data.WriteContentTo(xWriter);
    xWriter.Close();
}
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

I've seen similar things before, and been equally puzzled. It certainly *looks* like your code is doing the right thing. Having said that, I can't actually reproduce the problem *right now*. (I've seen it before though...)

Unless someone can work out what's going on, here's my suggested workaround:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = "\t" };

using (var stream = File.Create(sOutputFileName))
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        data.WriteContentTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'm a huge idiot, I DID have another stream that opened this file somewhere else. I completely forgot about it, and I have brought great shame to my family. A lesson for everyone else - always close your file streams!

Comment: @somethings_afoot: Okay... I think I'll delete this answer in a few minutes then, and vote to close the question as "too localized".